# Сравнения ников на оригинальность

Tags: python, бот

Есть код, который берет последних 100 входящих людей и банит их при условии отсутствии аватарки либо если их ник в бане. Но бывает такое, что может зайти два или более человека с одним и тем же ником. Как можно сделать, чтобы бот мог сам сравнивать ники входящих людей и если видел повторяющиеся - выдавал всем бан?
Официальная документация amino.py

https://aminopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/amino.html

```
banID = []
with open("banID.txt", "r+") as file:
    for lines in file:
        uid = lines.strip("\n")
        if not uid in banID: banID.append(uid)
def bann(subclient):
    while True:
        try:
            users = subclient.get_all_users(size=100).profile
            m_list = []
            for name, userId, icon in zip(users.nickname, users.userId, users.icon):
                if icon is None or name in blacklist:
                    m = threading.Thread(target=subclient.ban, args=(userId, "Аккаунт бота/реклама"))
                    m.start()
                    m_list.append(m)
                    banID.append(userId)
                    with open("banID.txt", "a") as file:
                        file.writelines(f"{str(userId)}\n")
                    print(f'Ban {name}')
                elif userId in banID:
                    m = threading.Thread(target = subclient.ban, args = (userId, "Противный рейдер"))
                    m.start()
                    m_list.append(m)
                    print(f'Ban {name}')
            for m in m_list:
                m.join()
        except Exception as meov:
            print(meov)


for com_id in com_ids:
    threading.Thread(target=bann, args=(sclients[int(com_id)],)).start()
```

Comment: могу посоветовать сохранять ники людей в списке(файле) и через if сравнивать их на повторение

Comment: Как записать их в файл я понимаю, но я не могу понять как сделать условие проверки на повторение? Хоть убей, не могу понять

Comment: Ну я бы в вашем случае использовал список а не файл, и через for переменная in список_юзеров проверял наличие name из теми которые в списке

Comment: тоесть if имя_нового_юзера == имя_из_списка: ваш код

Comment: и else: записать как нового юзера

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно связывать параметр name и uid. Бан возможен именно по uid

Comment: `from collections import Counter;l = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2];Counter(l)` Вам это нужно?